# Индикатор процесса загрузки файла

Tags: gwt, java

Можно ли сделать индикатор процесса загрузки файла на сервер (отображать процент загруженного файла) без GET запросов в течение загрузки (очень популярный пример в интернете)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взгляните на библиотеку [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) — она очень проста в использовать и прекрасно работает во всех браузерах и ОС, я проверял. Она использует `Ajax` запросы для расчета прогресса. Кстати `SWFUpload` не работает в Linux и Mac.
Пока что это лучшее решение для GWT.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё можно использовать comet, но это довольно мучительно, много проблем с переносимостью. Зато latency будет намного лучше, чем у нескольких GET'ов.

Comment: Можете написать подробнее. Особенно интересно, как сделать такую загрузку в Gwt.

Comment: Так же как в случае с многими GET'ми, только делается один GET, которые не заканчивается, а данные постепенно приходят. Т.е. не требуется делать повторный GET или пытаться угадать частоту обращений к серверу. Сервер сам может решать, когда и сколько данных клиенту посылать.

Поищите в гугле про COMET. Эта техника ещё набирает обороты и имеет свои проблемы, но информации по нему много.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто предположила, что ребята из гугл уже сделали в своей библиотеке что-то для этого.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/rocket-gwt/wiki/Comet

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/

Сам имел дело только с первым.

Answer (score 1):

ну многие юзают флешь - ам скорее всего что то встроенное есть - не специалист - говорить не буду. возможно есть какие то другие библиотеки

насчет сервера - вы получаете post запрос. возможно в заголовке будет указан размер пакета(файла) - если поток парсите (по крайней мере я такую задачу делал на апаче - есть память-буфер на сервере - 2 метра и юзер заливает 100 метровый файл - алгоритм мутный очень сильно привязанк веб протоколу, но можно сделать однопроходным). ну так вот в подобном алгоритме вы всегда можете понять сколько уже сохранили от клиента. если отнять от величину указанной в заголовке уже полученный размер - и сохранить величину в какой нибудь memcache - то периодическим вторым запросом от клинта можно получать и отображать информацию о загрузке.

Делать руками - можно но слишком долго и муторно. возможно некоторые веб серверы автоматически предоставляют нужный функционал - например какой нибудь каллбек при считывании очередных 2 мегабайт от клиента

я делал это на с. но в яве (в сервлете) тоже возможно получить поток и парсить его самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть, как работает GMail при прикреплении файла к письму. Посылаемые запросы можно просмотреть с помощью Fire Bug.

Answer (score 0):

без запросов - никак)))
только очень примерно, и то парочку придется сделать
делай их просто редкими, вернее, в начале частые, считай скорость, а потом уточняй редкими запросами

хотя, возможно, это и вытягивается из браузера. но примеров не встречал. думаю, проще кинуть 5 GET

Comment: @uramer239 Вместо создания нового ответа правильно редактировать свой предыдущий.

Comment: ок, учту