# Как подсчитывать объем переданной информации через iframe?

Tags: ajax, javascript

У меня есть загрузчик файлов, передающий данные на основе iframe (только не пойму, какое это имеет отношение к ajax), необходимо создать индикатор загрузки (progress bar).

Как подсчитывать количество переданных данных? Надо считать объем HTTP-заголовков? (Если да, то как это делается? И как его связать именно с iframe?)

Answer (score 0):

Такой вопрос уже задавался. Как минимум, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829/). В любом случае, подсчёт переданных данных надо делать на сервере. Вы можете либо периодически опрашивать аяксом сервер, обновлять прогресс загрузки, либо использовать comet.